Clarification on Apple Push Notification Service Server Certificate Update (for Firebase)
I received an email notifying about change on APNs Trust Store. I don't know if I must do something regarding on Firebase Notificatiion. Is this change handled by Firebase, or I have to make any actions on my app notification setup?
I don't know what can I do to update the certificates. I think this is handled by Firebase but I'm not sure.

+1 here, as far as i understand if you're just using firebase, it is handled by google and they will update it on their end.

From what Apple developer said:

This certificate update is only needed for developers who are running
their own push servers to directly communicate with APNs.
3rd party push providers will need to handle this certificate update
on their end.
If you are not certain that your provider may not be ready for this
update, you would want to double check with them.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/770316
In this case, Firebase will handle it by themselves.

Some people have asked similar questions, you can refer to the following, Firebase will help to update it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79203819/5957749
